# iPhone App in AppStore crashes on startup

Tags: iphone, crash, app-store, startup

I have an application in the appstore that has been tested by apple and me. I ran it on my iPhone 4 device, iPad Simulator, iPhone Simulator and it is working properly.

However, some users are reviewing that the app crashes on startup. I dont have any other informations as there are no crash reports and I cant contact the reviewers.

I had a similar problem when i had "Architecture: Standard (armv7)", then it crashed on some devices. I changed it to armv6 and armv7 and thought it would fix the problem, but seems like i was wrong.

Do you have an idea?
Thanks for your help

[app store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/3100-unglaubliche-fakten/id434894484?) to my application, maybe someone wants to download it, it is free

Crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: E866F016-7F94-472E-9C62-9872E2072B45
CrashReporter Key:   e00f15ad3349d73bfc3666ab3634a523caa83113
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Facts [2619]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0CAB9978-F9AE-41FB-B795-D078AB78D2C9/Facts.app/Facts
Identifier:      Facts
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-10-27 16:56:30.759 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34bbfa1c 0x34bae000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bf93b4 0x34bc6000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bf1bf8 0x34bc6000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33cb2a64 0x33c6e000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3417206c 0x3416c000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33cb0e36 0x33c6e000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33cb0e8a 0x33c6e000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33cb0f5a 0x33c6e000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34170c84 0x3416c000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x36f1b1b8 0x36e79000 + 663992
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36f1a642 0x36e79000 + 661058
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36e91178 0x36e79000 + 98680
12  UIKit                           0x35f681c8 0x35cfd000 + 2535880
13  UIKit                           0x35f67d92 0x35cfd000 + 2534802
14  UIKit                           0x35f68340 0x35cfd000 + 2536256
15  UIKit                           0x35f070d4 0x35cfd000 + 2138324
16  UIKit                           0x35fcae80 0x35cfd000 + 2940544
17  UIKit                           0x35f681c8 0x35cfd000 + 2535880
18  UIKit                           0x35f67d92 0x35cfd000 + 2534802
19  UIKit                           0x35f68340 0x35cfd000 + 2536256
20  UIKit                           0x35f067c0 0x35cfd000 + 2136000
21  UIKit                           0x35f07e02 0x35cfd000 + 2141698
22  UIKit                           0x35e815e2 0x35cfd000 + 1590754
23  UIKit                           0x35e4ef9e 0x35cfd000 + 1384350
24  UIKit                           0x35d33eb8 0x35cfd000 + 224952
25  UIKit                           0x35d711d4 0x35cfd000 + 475604
26  UIKit                           0x35d71186 0x35cfd000 + 475526
27  UIKit                           0x35d70a2c 0x35cfd000 + 473644
28  UIKit                           0x35df5ce4 0x35cfd000 + 1019108
29  UIKit                           0x35d7180a 0x35cfd000 + 477194
30  UIKit                           0x35d41b1c 0x35cfd000 + 281372
31  UIKit                           0x35d025f4 0x35cfd000 + 22004
32  CoreFoundation                  0x36e84efc 0x36e79000 + 48892
33  QuartzCore                      0x31344bae 0x31342000 + 11182
34  QuartzCore                      0x31344966 0x31342000 + 10598
35  QuartzCore                      0x3134a1be 0x31342000 + 33214
36  QuartzCore                      0x31349fd0 0x31342000 + 32720
37  QuartzCore                      0x31355df8 0x31342000 + 81400
38  QuartzCore                      0x31355dc6 0x31342000 + 81350
39  UIKit                           0x35d4191c 0x35cfd000 + 280860
40  UIKit                           0x35d2cc1c 0x35cfd000 + 195612
41  UIKit                           0x35d017d0 0x35cfd000 + 18384
42  UIKit                           0x35d0120e 0x35cfd000 + 16910
43  UIKit                           0x35d00c4c 0x35cfd000 + 15436
44  GraphicsServices                0x3663be70 0x36637000 + 20080
45  CoreFoundation                  0x36eeea90 0x36e79000 + 481936
46  CoreFoundation                  0x36ef0838 0x36e79000 + 489528
47  CoreFoundation                  0x36ef1606 0x36e79000 + 493062
48  CoreFoundation                  0x36e81ebc 0x36e79000 + 36540
49  CoreFoundation                  0x36e81dc4 0x36e79000 + 36292
50  UIKit                           0x35d2bd42 0x35cfd000 + 191810
51  UIKit                           0x35d29800 0x35cfd000 + 182272
52  Facts                           0x0000223e 0x1000 + 4670
53  Facts                           0x000021fc 0x1000 + 4604

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34bc03ec 0x34bae000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bfa6d8 0x34bc6000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bfabbc 0x34bc6000 + 215996
Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34bc0fbc 0x34bae000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d91032 0x33d8b000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d9203a 0x33d8b000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d915ea 0x33d8b000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bfa58a 0x34bc6000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bfabbc 0x34bc6000 + 215996

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34bbdc00 0x34bae000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34bbd758 0x34bae000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36eef2b8 0x36e79000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36ef1562 0x36e79000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36e81ebc 0x36e79000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36e81dc4 0x36e79000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x3664a27e 0x36644000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bf930a 0x34bc6000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34bfabb4 0x34bc6000 + 215988
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f43b48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x04a29e2c      r7: 0x2fdfc6ec
    r8: 0x3f7a6e84    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x04a29bc0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfc6e0      lr: 0x34bf93bb      pc: 0x34bbfa1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
Binary Images:
```

Comment: please see my comment above. Did you get an error or something that can help us?

Comment: iphone4 device i used to check

Comment: Then how you are alloc the memory and inserting in to your view\

Comment: i just redownloaded the app on my iphone 4 and it is working. wtf. can you post the content of the crash log?

Comment: did u got any solution for your issue

Comment: seems like it crashes on firmware which are not iOS 5! Thanks for the report

Comment: i need one help how to see the crash binary to words can you tell the steps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4565/discussion-between-dooonot-and-ceacare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently added UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the app and did not catch it, if the Class is not found. So all firmwares below 5.0 crashed. I did not test that, because I don't have the 4.x simulator anymore. Thanks to the crash report from ceacare, I saw that it crashed on 4.3.5. I removed the references to this class and will push an update immediatelly. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but here is a least one thing to think about:

What is your application doing at startup?  iOS has a built-in watchdog which will shut your application down if it takes longer than 5 seconds to start.  Is there anything that you app is doing which might make it exceed those 5 seconds?  For example,

1) Opening a network connection.  If users in other locations have a slower connection than your testing location, maybe something that finishes for you is not finishing for them.  Maybe they are on a 3G network with poor reception or something.

2) Loading large files. Are you loading anything big or perhaps a number of view controllers from a single nib file?  Maybe other devices load things more slowly which makes them exceed the 5 second limit.

If you do anything time consuming in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, try to move it somewhere else or put it in a background thread and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If the application opens for the first time, i create a sqlite3 database and insert like 3100 items. I don't know how it acts on an old device :(

Comment: That sounds like the kind of thing that might trigger the watchdog.  Can you do that in the background, or do it after applicationDidFinishLaunching:?

Comment: yeah sure, but i can't check it, as it is not reproducable. at least not for me :( any idea how to test that?